# mysql group max value rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am having this table: 
 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3223/1

```
id  entity_id   value   date
1   1           98      March, 28 2015 19:58:43
2   1           321     March, 28 2015 19:59:54
3   1           123     March, 28 2015 19:59:54
4   2           34      March, 28 2015 20:00:43
5   2           76      March, 28 2015 20:00:44
```

And I want to list the **newest row** (by `date` value)  for each `entity_id`.

The first solution, and the wrong one also is: - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3223/2

```
SELECT id, entity_id, value, MAX(  `date` ) 
FROM  `gmd` 
GROUP BY entity_id
```

One of the working solutions seems to be:
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3223/3

```
SELECT id, entity_id, value,  `date` 
FROM gmd AS main
WHERE DATE = ( 
    SELECT MAX(  `date` ) 
    FROM gmd
    WHERE entity_id = main.entity_id 
) 
GROUP BY entity_id
```

I am wondering if this is a reliable solution and if there are other more elegant ways to do that.

Thank you!

Comment: And for 2 same dates? Display both records for each entity?

Comment: Check your second query result with some data change http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce5ab/1

Comment: @Beginner , I see your point, but in this case the result it's still ok because both dates are equal. Although there can be a second value to compare withand that can be the highest ID .

Comment: @SerbuFlorin-Adrian In that case see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you always want to get the value having highest `id` if they have same `date`:

```
SELECT id, entity_id, value, 
  (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM gmd y WHERE y.id = x.id) AS `date`
FROM  `gmd` x
GROUP BY entity_id DESC
ORDER BY id;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce5ab/7).

Comment: Indeed, that's seems to be a better solution, although the 'by last ID' ordering must be done somehow internally by not being specified in the query. And it looks much better that my working solution, thank you!

PS: Can you leave me a hint on why it actually selects the latest ID ?

Comment: `GROUP BY entity_id DESC` try removing `DESC`

Answer (score 1):

This is another way, but as you can see, there is a tie:

```
select id, entity_id, value, `date`
  from gmd x
  join (select entity_id, max(date) as `date` from gmd group by entity_id) y
 using (entity_id, `date`)
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3223/11/0

In your 'working' query, an arbitrary (random) value for the `value` field is being chosen, since it is not in your `group by` clause. In most other databases -- other than MySQL -- this would return a syntax error.

If you don't want both values for `value` brought back in the event of a tie between 2 values of `value` for the same `entity_id` and `date` how do you want to decide which value of `value` to bring back?

Edit based on comments --
If you want the 'last' row inserted there needs to be some way of establishing order beyond the `date`. Assuming that that the `id` field ascends with time, you can join into the max `id` for each `entity_id` this way:

```
select id, entity_id, value, `date`
  from gmd x
  join (select entity_id, max(id) as id from gmd group by entity_id) y
 using (entity_id, id)
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3223/35/0

Comment: Let's say if there is the case where two dates would be equal for the same entity id, I can pick the one that was inserted last. But your query seems to be a bit more 'aware' of that and it returns both values in that case, which can be useful. 

I suppose by "In your 'working' query" you are referring to the first non-working query. Correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: You only posted two queries, you said the first was wrong and that the second was working. I was referring to the second. However they both have a group by clause that excludes columns in the select list despite aggregate functions being in the select list, so they both have the 'choosing arbitrary rows' issue and would both return a syntax error in any database other than MySQL. I've added a 2nd query that should grab the 'last inserted row' assuming that your `id` column is an auto increment field.